# Corrupted files when downloaded from IIS

Tags: perl, iis

All files that are on my IIS intranet, when downloaded become corrupted.
If I open them on the server they are OK.
If I copy them locally on my PC (transferring the file by File Explorer)
they are OK.
But if I create an Intranet page with a link on them and then I download
them using my browser, when they arrive on my PC they are slightly larger and
corrupted.
It seems like IIS is corrupting them during the file transfer.

Thanks

Comment: How does Perl come in to this?

Comment: I create the internet page with perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) on your output file handles? If you don't set the output streams to binary mode then plain newlines (`\n` or more accurately `\x0a`) will be converted to Windows-style CR-LF (`\x0d\x0a`), that conversion would explain the size increase and the corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the files you are trying to download, are supported MIME-Types in IIS?    If the MIME-types aren't set, you can add them fairly easily in IIS.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a permissions thing then.  Either with the IIS_User or however the user is accessing file.